# Is there any way to identify if my server is HyperV VM or a physical machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I want to know is there any way to detect that the current server i am using is physical box or Hyper V Virtual machine.

Is there any thing in windows that could tell me about it?
Any setting, registry key in windows ?
Or any script that could tell me that?

I do not have physical access to server, only can logon to server.

Comment: Check this out: [Hyper-V: How to Detect if a Computer is a VM Using Script](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/942.hyper-v-how-to-detect-if-a-computer-is-a-vm-using-script.aspx)

Comment: eh, no offence, but I think my answer is better. Should this be closed, mind cribbing the best bits and incorporating it into yours? I *suspect* we started at the same point, but I ended up poking into it a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wmic (or script it with wmi yourself).Use the command `wmic baseboard get manufacturer,product` and check the values there.

If manufacturer reads Microsoft (or vmware or Oracle), its likely a vm, with the VM host being named as the product. I don't currently have a hyper V box, but virtualbox identifies itself as being manufactured by oracle, and virtualbox as the product.

My laptop has Lenovo as the manufacturer, and the full SKU as the model. You'll likely find similar behaviors between VM software, and actual hardware. My desktop has Asustek as the manufacturer and the motherboard model as the product

This should be sufficient to work out if your system is in a VM or not.

Comment: If manufacturer reads Microsoft it could be a microsoft surface pro too, hence will be a false positive

Comment: MS didn't make PCs when I posted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can open `msinfo32.exe` and check the System Summary.

*System Model* shows whether the Machine is Virtual/Physical.

**Physical machines**: [image]

***Virtual Machines***:[image]

Comment: There's a lot of information in there. What should we look for?

Comment: _System Manufacturer_, _System Model_ and _BIOS/version_ would give you clues whether the OS is virtual or physical. Initially I didn't put these exact variables in the answer because there didn't seem to be that many and it might have been pretty obvious. thanks.